# Лицензия: можно ли использовать файловые виды предоставляемого кода?

Tags: веб-программирование, авторские-права, юридические-аспекты

Задался таким вопросом, если вдруг хочется использовать скрипты и прочее не через сайты, к примеру, Google, а через файлы в папках своего сайта, не будет ли это нарушением прав? Т.е. я создаю файл с названием скрипта, который лежит в корне Google, к которому имеют обычный доступ сотни сайтов, переношу туда код, и сохраняю файл, имея уже тот же скрипт с удалённого Google, но у себя. Как бы то не было странно, но я не нарушаю ничего? Даже с переносом текста вначале файла, где пишут обычно автора и прочее.

Comment: О чём это?  Какой перенос кода?  Какого кода?  Какие файлы в корне Гугла?

Что это вообще за бред?

Comment: Бред - это когда вы не понимаете и кипишуете, вот пример =)
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Ну "файлы в корне Гугла" -- это серьёзно. Налицо либо попытка использовать незнакомую терминологию (см. термин "сфотографировать" в "Янки при дворе короля Артура"), либо автор имеет немалый вес в компании Google.

Comment: я генеральный директор Google

Comment: "            "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае указанный скрипт распространяется под [лицензией MIT](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt)

В переводе на нормальный язык дозволяется делать практически все что угодно, при условии что исходник будет иметь ссылку на данную лицензию или ее текст

Есличо перевод лицензии [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CB%E8%F6%E5%ED%E7%E8%FF_MIT)

Comment: а как узнать лицензию этого скрипта? jQuery MotionCAPTCHA v0.2
есть ли они в какой - то базе все?

Comment: Ткните на исходник и увидите в шапке лицензию:
>/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
>(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return

Comment: т.е все jquery скрипты относятся к лицензии jquery.org/license/ и являются свободными?

Comment: т.е. MotionCAPTCHA на бесплатной лицензии?

Comment: понятно -.-"

Answer (score 1):

Это надо не здесь спрашивать, а читать в лицензии для каждого конкретного случая.

Comment: вполне конкретный и, насколько я понимаю, правильный ответ.