# Лицензия MIT и свободное распространение

Tags: текст, лицензирование, opensource, авторские-права

Могу ли я свободно распространять файлы без атрибутов и ссылок программы, с помощью которой я его сделал?
(Пример: есть программка с лицензией MIT (текстовый редактор), могу ли я сделать скриншот и прикреплю к скриншоту документ, без атрибутов (где этот файл был сделан, что за программа на скриншоте, ссылка на сайт производителя ит.д.)
Пример программ: Joplin, Notable, Remarkable

Comment: **Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.** Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798757/262779

Comment: 1. «лицензия mit» — некорректное название, т.к. mit использовал разные лицензии. чаще под этим термином подразумевают [лицензию x11](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.ru.html#X11License), реже [лицензию expat](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.ru.html#Expat). 2. насколько мне известно, в природе не существует лицензий на программное обеспечение, содержащих какие-либо требования на изготовление/распространение снимков экранов, содержащих фрагменты изображения, сформированного этим программным обеспечением.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Лицензия: можно ли использовать файловые виды предоставляемого кода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163883/%d0%9b%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: Уже отвечал на схожий вопрос - смотрите на ссылку [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163883/Лицензия-можно-ли-использовать-файловые-виды-предоставляемого-кода/163893#163893](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163883/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/163893#163893

Comment: @Barmaley, я бы не сказал, что это схожий вопрос. Тем более тот вопрос сформулирован настолько мутно, что там вообще не понять о чем речь. Не будь он таким старым, я бы проголосовал за закрытие.

Answer (score 1):

Лицензия программного обеспечения не относится к скриншотам. Обычно любая лицензия содержит исчерпывающее перечисление прав, которые она регулирует, например "*the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the software*".

Я не юрист и не могу утверждать на 100%, но по-моему, право сделать скриншот вообще невозможно ограничить лицензионным соглашением. Так же, как фотография улицы не подразумевает выплат роялти всем архитекторам домов и производителям автомобилей, попавших в кадр.